# table-responsive not working in bootstrap 3

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using bootstrap 3 for a website project. I'm trying to create a page with a responsive table, so that I'd have the scrollbar when the table is too big. I made a test case like so:

```
    <div class="col-md-10">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading main-color-bg">
                <h3 class="panel-title">بازرسی انجام نشده</h3>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <div class="table-responsive">
                    <table class="table table-striped table-hover">
                        <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>کد درخواست</th>
                            <th>نام آموزشگاه</th>
                            <th>شماره ملی مؤسس</th>
                            <th>فعالیت گروه</th>
                            <th>شهرستان</th>
                            <th>نام و نام خانوادگی مؤسس</th>
                            <th>کد ملی</th>
                            <th>موبایل</th>
                            <th>شماره تماس آموزشگاه</th>
                            <th>آدرس</th>
                            <th>نمایش جزئیات</th>
                        </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                        @foreach($schools as $school)
                                    <tr>
                                        <td class="translate">{{ $school->id }}</td>
                                        <td>{{ $school->school_name }}</td>
                                        <td class="translate">{{ $school->national_number_founder }}</td>
                                        <td>{{ $activity->group->group_name }}</td>
                                        <td>{{ $school->cities->city_name }}</td>
                                        <td>{{ $school->user->first_name }} {{ $school->user->last_name }}</td>
                                        <td class="translate">{{ $school->user->national_code }}</td>
                                        <td class="translate">{{ $school->user->mobile }}</td>
                                        <td class="translate">{{ $school->phone }}</td>
                                        <td>{{ $school->address }}</td>

                                        <td>
                                            <a href="{{ route('inspection-register.show', ['id' => $school->id]) }}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt"></span></a>
                                            <a href="{{ route('schools-list.index') }}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></a>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                @endforeach
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Now, the problem is that it doesn't add the scrollbar, it merely expands the website to the width of the table.

See a screenshot here:

[table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QB56y.png)

I've seen it working on several other websites, so something I'm doing...is wrong.

Comment: any console errors?

Answer (score 0):

Created this [pen](https://codepen.io/SubSul/pen/pxgRBY) with your code, you resize the window and the scroll bar appears automatically. I have copied your code as-is and just added the `bootstrap-3` dependencies.

Code:

```html
<html>
<head>
  <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
  <div class="col-md-10">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading main-color-bg">
        <h3 class="panel-title">بازرسی انجام نشده</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="table-responsive">
          <table class="table table-striped table-hover">
            <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>کد درخواست</th>
              <th>نام آموزشگاه</th>
              <th>شماره ملی مؤسس</th>
              <th>فعالیت گروه</th>
              <th>شهرستان</th>
              <th>نام و نام خانوادگی مؤسس</th>
              <th>کد ملی</th>
              <th>موبایل</th>
              <th>شماره تماس آموزشگاه</th>
              <th>آدرس</th>
              <th>نمایش جزئیات</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td class="translate">1</td>
              <td>1</td>
              <td class="translate">1</td>
              <td>1</td>
              <td>1</td>
              <td>1</td>
              <td class="translate">1</td>
              <td class="translate">1</td>
              <td class="translate">1</td>
              <td>1</td>
              <td>
                <a href="{{ route('inspection-register.show', ['id' => $school->id]) }}"><span
                  class="glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt"></span></a>
                <a href="{{ route('schools-list.index') }}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></a>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="translate">2</td>
              <td>2</td>
              <td class="translate">2</td>
              <td>2</td>
              <td>2</td>
              <td>2</td>
              <td class="translate">2</td>
              <td class="translate">2</td>
              <td class="translate">2</td>
              <td>2</td>
              <td>
                <a href="{{ route('inspection-register.show', ['id' => $school->id]) }}"><span
                  class="glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt"></span></a>
                <a href="{{ route('schools-list.index') }}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></a>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="translate">3</td>
              <td>3</td>
              <td class="translate">3</td>
              <td>3</td>
              <td>3</td>
              <td>3</td>
              <td class="translate">3</td>
              <td class="translate">3</td>
              <td class="translate">3</td>
              <td>3</td>
              <td>
                <a href="{{ route('inspection-register.show', ['id' => $school->id]) }}"><span
                  class="glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt"></span></a>
                <a href="{{ route('schools-list.index') }}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></a>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="translate">4</td>
              <td>4</td>
              <td class="translate">4</td>
              <td>4</td>
              <td>4</td>
              <td>4</td>
              <td class="translate">4</td>
              <td class="translate">4</td>
              <td class="translate">4</td>
              <td>4</td>
              <td>
                <a href="{{ route('inspection-register.show', ['id' => $school->id]) }}"><span
                  class="glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt"></span></a>
                <a href="{{ route('schools-list.index') }}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></a>
              </td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css"
      integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">
<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Adding `overflow-x` will make it work across all layouts

```
.table-responsive
{
    overflow-x: auto;
}
```